# Size of _SFR_IO_ADDR() result in AVR GCC

Tags: c, gcc, avr

I am in a situation where I need to save addresses of IO ports to variables.

I've found that eg. `_SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB)` gives address of PORTB.

What data type do I need to reliably contain the result of this macro? Will `uint8_t` suffice?

(I tried to google it, found nothing - sorry.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to just use a pointer. GCC will [Do The Right Thing](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_port_pass).

```
volatile char *pb = &PORTB;
```

Comment: It probably will, but no one does it that way.